# issue with positioning css divider lines in menu

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS problem that I've been unable to figure out. Basically, I have a menu which is a fixed width and height. The background of the menu is simply a graphic, with a gray bar, and a drop shadow beneath. Here is the css for that menu:

```
  #menu
   {
       width:1024px;
       height:63px;
       background: url(../images/menuholder.jpg);
       margin:0px;
   }
```

I have a CMS controlling the menu options, however for this example, I have them hardcoded. I am using CSS to position the elements in the correct place vertically, over the gray bar, centered vertically, which is fine. Here is the issue: I am trying to place a 1px wide white (#fff) line in between each menu option. I would prefer to do this via CSS entirely, rather than with a saved image. I was able to do it (sort of) using this code:

```
<div id="menu">
            <div id="upperNavLinks">
            <ul>
              <li style="border-right: 1px solid #fff;"><a href="Option1.aspx" target="_self">Option 1</a></li>
              <li style="border-right: 1px solid #fff;"><a href="Option2.aspx" target="_self">Option 2</a></li>
              <li style="border-right: 1px solid #fff;"><a href="Option3.aspx" target="_self">Option 3</a></li>
              <li style="border-right: 1px solid #fff;"><a href="Option4.aspx" target="_self">Option 4</a></li>
              <li style="border-right: 1px solid #fff;"><a href="Option5.aspx" target="_self">Option 5</a></li>
            </ul>   
            </div>
         </div>
```

The css behind it is:

```
#upperNavLinks
{
    float:left;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-left:0px;  
}

#upperNavLinks ul
{
    list-style-type:none; 
}

#upperNavLinks ul li
{
    float:left;
}

#upperNavLinks ul a {
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:PT Sans, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #333333;
}

#upperNavLinks ul a:hover 
{
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #a31624;
}
```

The problem is, it generates a white line where I want it to, however I need it to start at the top of the gray bar, and proceed down to the bottom of the gray bar, but not over the drop shadow. The size (vertically) of the gray bar is : 44px.

So, the question I have is: How do I make the white line lock to the top of the gray bar, and cover 44px (and not over) of vertical space over the gray bar, while leaving the actual menu options floating in the center of the graphic as they are now?

If this doesnt make any sense I could post the actual graphic and code somewhere.

Comment: its better to provide actual code with graphic

Answer (score 0):

Between each `li` with an anchor, place another `li`, now with a class (I named it border). Give that class a `display: block;`, a `width: 1px;` and a `height: 20px;`.Now you can play with the height to get the effect you looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/4hJrb/1/

Answer (score 0):

What's the semantic implications of placing empty

's? Personaly I would use background image for something like this rather than creating empty tags.